# Графический отладчик

Tags: haskell

Существует ли графический отладчик для языка Haskell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для Eclipse есть такие [плагины](http://eclipsefp.github.com/), которые дают возможность пошаговой отладки (выставления точек останова, просмотра значений переменных) модулей.

Comment: я сейчас поставил себе leksah - он у меня как на macos так и на windows не может найти модуль IO, не знаете как исправить?

Comment: Прописать в свойствах проекта, в разделе "Зависимости"

Answer (score 2):

**Web редактор + отладчик**: [FP Complete](https://www.fpcomplete.com/)

также поддержка актуальной и корректно сегнерированной документации, наскоько я помню, с **stackage**.

**Desktop версия:** однозначно [Leksah](http://leksah.org/).

**Также по теме стоит почитать:**

[Haskell - garbage collector](https://anton-k.github.io/ru-haskell-book/book/10.html)
здесь описана в том числе визуализация по работе с GC.

[Haskell - Средства разработки](https://anton-k.github.io/ru-haskell-book/book/18.html)

Answer (score 0):

Имеется ввиду не "графический отладчик", а отладчик с GUI, видимо?

Вообще нынче это все интегрировано. И называется IDE (интегрированная среда разработки).

Смотрим и выбираем:
http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/IDEs
Конечно, игнорируем простые редакторы, смотрим только то, что является полноценным IDE. Тут тебе и уже упомянутые Leksah и Eclipse и др.

В частности, у меня Leksah может breakpoint.